# Getting selected values from dropdown inside table

Tags: javascript, html

For now I can get the selected values from the event onchange in my dropdown inside my table but it only works on the first row of my table. If I am going to change values from other rows it will still getting the value from the first row.

Here is my code:

```
<table class="sortable" border="1" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee Serial</th>
            <th>Grade</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr style="font-size:11px">
                <td>@item.empSerial</td>

                <td ALIGN="center">
                    <select onchange="getSelValue()" id="drpTechnical" class="testerDrop" style="height:20px; width:100px; text-align-last:center; cursor:pointer">
                        <option value=@item.technicalComp>@item.grade1</option>
                        <option value=@item.empSerial>0</option>
                        <option value=@item.empSerial>1</option>
                        <option value=@item.empSerial>2</option>
                        <option value=@item.empSerial>3</option>
                        <option value=@item.empSerial>4</option>
                    </select>
                </td>                    

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And simple script to read the selected values:

```
function getSelValue() {        
        alert(document.getElementById("drpTechnical").value)         
    }
```

Comment: Pass current element content `this` i.e. `onchange="getSelValue(this)"` and in the function `alert(this.value)   `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById` returns allways only the first element with this ID since IDs should be unique.

What you want is to get the id from that element that has been changed. So you need `this`

```
function getSelValue(this) {        
    alert(this.value)         
}
```

And your table should look like this

```
<td ALIGN="center">
  <select onchange="getSelValue(this)" id="drpTechnical" class="testerDrop" style="height:20px; width:100px; text-align-last:center; cursor:pointer">
    <option value=@item.technicalComp>@item.grade1</option>
    <option value=@item.empSerial>0</option>
    <option value=@item.empSerial>1</option>
    <option value=@item.empSerial>2</option>
    <option value=@item.empSerial>3</option>
    <option value=@item.empSerial>4</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you made a small mistake there, the id you set to the select tag is called "drpTechnical" but in the function you try to call element with id of "getSelValue"

Try change the codes like below
Code updates :

```
 <td ALIGN="center">
   <select onchange="getSelValue(this)" class="testerDrop" 
     style="height:20px; width:100px; text-align-last:center; cursor:pointer">
                    <option value=@item.technicalComp>@item.grade1</option>
                    <option value=@item.empSerial>0</option>
                    <option value=@item.empSerial>1</option>
                    <option value=@item.empSerial>2</option>
                    <option value=@item.empSerial>3</option>
                    <option value=@item.empSerial>4</option>
                </select>
            </td>     

<script>
function getSelValue(obj) {        
    alert(obj.value)         
}
</script>
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because ids should be unique. This would allways return the value of the first select.

Comment: ah yeah that's right, you can pass the select object to the function and then get the value by using obj.value, or you can change the id into a class instead

Comment: You can't change the id to a class instead. That would return the value of every select. Your first idea is what I've did in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getSelValue(e) {        
        alert(e.value)         
    }
```

```html
<table class="sortable" border="1" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee Serial</th>
            <th>Grade</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

            <tr style="font-size:11px">
                <td>@item.empSerial</td>

                <td ALIGN="center">
                    <select onchange="getSelValue(this)" id="drpTechnical" class="testerDrop" style="height:20px; width:100px; text-align-last:center; cursor:pointer">
                        <option value=@item.technicalComp>@item.grade1</option>
                        <option value=@item.empSerial>0</option>
                        <option value=@item.empSerial>1</option>
                        <option value=@item.empSerial>2</option>
                        <option value=@item.empSerial>3</option>
                        <option value=@item.empSerial>4</option>
                    </select>
                </td>                    

            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Try this.